# Cannot read contents from file.. Warning! file_get_contents Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, file

I have file type custom option.When i browse any image and add to cart the products then it shows me error.
Please check attached screenshot.

[image]

I have already give the permission.
Please help.Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: does the file exist ? have you checked the file permission make sure the file permission is 755

Comment: Yes, The file permission set to 755.

Comment: Also give writable access to /tmp/opt/lamp/temp, you can run  chmod -R 777 /tmp/opt/lamp/temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give proper permission and have to give proper user to `/tmp/opt/lampp/temp` folder.

***Apache user*** means **www-data**  don't have proper permission at that folder.

Comment: There is no any directory exist like /tmp/opt/lampp/temp .... But i have setup the project in /tmp/opt/lampp/htdocs/Ronnie_Work/magento226.So why error display like this? please check this screenshot..  http://nimb.ws/tDEwNU

Comment: please help me!!

Comment: create a folder at /tmp/opt/lampp/temp and check what happenn

Comment: Or  create  a folder name 'tmp` at pub/media/

Comment: No Luck !!!!!!!

Comment: Please check phpinfo. Check  upload_tmp_dir and sys_temp_dir property value

Comment: http://nimb.ws/dYltKM please check this screenshot and tell me is there anything wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Have u create `/tmp/opt/lampp/temp` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86324/discussion-between-sunny-rahevar-and-amit-bera).